# Python distinguish between abstract method and abstract attribute

Tags: python, abstract-class

In python, is there a way to enforce attribute vs method with an abstract class?

For example if I want to enforce a method like the following:

```py
class AbstractCar(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def drive():
    pass
```

then this class would still be fine to instantiate.

```py
class Car(AbstractCar):
  drive = 5 # This satisfies the @abstractmethod above but is not a method
```

or vice versa with:

```py
  @property
  @abstractmethod
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this, exactly? If someone overrides `drive()` and turns it into _not a method_, then their code will break when they try to use the object as an `AbstractCar`, which should be enough incentive for them to avoid doing this.

Comment: Don't feel the "need". Mainly trying to learn Python :)
@abstractmethod kinda suggests it should be an abstract method. Otherwise why does python feel the need to name it that? Why not abstractJimmy :)

Comment: You're not wrong, you've just detected a weak implementation in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would start using a type checker such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Whenever I write Python lately, I always try to keep it as safe as I can by using tools like flake8 and mypy for validations. Here's your code with some type-hints added:

`test.py`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AbstractCar(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def drive(self) -> None:
        pass


class Car(AbstractCar):
    drive = 5
```

And here is the warning for doing this type of override:

```
$ mypy test.py
mypy.py:10: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int",
base class "AbstractCar" defined the type as "Callable[[AbstractCar], None]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```